# Bean property is not writeable .Invalid setter method in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, spring-batch, hypersql

[image]> I want to store data in an embed database .I fetch some predefined

> data and store these data in databse. I don't know which type of data
> that are, SO i declared every things datatype as string . when i
> convert date string data into local date and try to store in database
> it throw this error

```
org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException: Parsing error at line: 1 in resource=[class path resource [result-match-metadata.csv]], input=[id   city    date    player_of_match venue   neutral_venue   team1   team2   toss_winner toss_decision   winner  result  result_margin   eliminator  method  umpire1 umpire2]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doRead(FlatFileItemReader.java:189) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:93) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:99) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:180) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:126) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:118) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:71) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:258) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:208) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:152) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:68) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:68) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:137) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:320) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:149) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:140) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:128) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy82.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.execute(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:199) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:173) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:160) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:155) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:150) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:782) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:772) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:345) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at com.nilmani.dashboardipl.DashboardIplApplicationKt.main(DashboardIplApplication.kt:13) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.IncorrectTokenCountException: Incorrect number of tokens found in record: expected 17 actual 1
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.AbstractLineTokenizer.tokenize(AbstractLineTokenizer.java:143) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper.mapLine(DefaultLineMapper.java:43) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doRead(FlatFileItemReader.java:185) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    ... 56 common frames omitted
```

> MatchInput.kt

```
package com.nilmani.dashboardipl.data

data class MatchInput(
     val id: String? = null,
     val city: String? = null,
     val date: String? = null,
     val player_of_match: String? = null,
     val venue: String? = null,
     val neutral_venue: String? = null,
     val team1: String? = null,
     val team2: String? = null,
     val toss_winner: String? = null,
     val toss_decision: String? = null,
     val winner: String? = null,
     val result: String? = null,
     val result_margin: String? = null,
     val eliminator: String? = null,
     val method: String? = null,
     val umpire1: String? = null,
     val umpire2: String? = null,
)
```

> matchitemprocessor.kt

```
package com.nilmani.dashboardipl.data

import com.nilmani.dashboardipl.entity.Match
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor
import java.time.LocalDate

class MatchInputItemProcessor : ItemProcessor<MatchInput,Match> {
    val log:Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MatchInputItemProcessor::class.java)
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun process(item: MatchInput): Match? {
        val match =Match()
        match.id = java.lang.Long.valueOf(item.id)
        match.city= item.city
        match.date = LocalDate.parse(item.date)
        match.playerOfMatch = item.player_of_match
        match.venue = item.venue
        /** set Team 1 and Team 2 depending on the innings*/
        val firstIngTeam:String
        val secondIngTeam:String
        if ("bat" == item.toss_decision){
            firstIngTeam = item.toss_winner.toString()
            secondIngTeam =
                if (item.toss_winner.equals(item.team1))item.team2.toString()
                else
                    item.team1.toString()
        }else{
            secondIngTeam = item.toss_winner.toString()
            firstIngTeam =
                if (item.toss_winner.equals(item.team1))item.team2.toString()
                else
                    item.team1.toString()
        }
        match.team1 = firstIngTeam
        match.team2 = secondIngTeam
        match.tossWinner = item.toss_winner
        match.tossDecision = item.toss_decision
        match.result = item.result
        match.resultMargin = item.result_margin
        match.umpire1= item.umpire1
        match.umpire2 = item.umpire2
        return match
    }

}
```

> batchconfig.kt

```
@Bean
    fun reader(): FlatFileItemReader<MatchInput> {
        return FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<MatchInput>()
            .name("MatchItemReader")
            .resource(ClassPathResource("match-data.csv"))
            .delimited()
            .names(*FIELD_NAMES)
            .fieldSetMapper(object : BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<MatchInput>() {
                init {
                    setTargetType(MatchInput::class.java)
                }
            })
            .build()
    }
```

> Match.kt

```
package com.nilmani.dashboardipl.entity

import java.time.LocalDate
import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.Id

@Entity
data class Match(
    @Id
    var id: Long = 0,
    var city: String? = null,
    var date: LocalDate? = null,
    var playerOfMatch: String? = null,
    var venue: String? = null,
    var team1: String? = null,
    var team2: String? = null,
    var tossWinner: String? = null,
    var tossDecision: String? = null,
    val matchWinner: String? = null,
    var result: String? = null,
    var resultMargin: String? = null,
    var umpire1: String? = null,
    var umpire2: String? = null

)
```

> I want store csv data in to database

> here is the FIELD_NAMES

```
val FIELD_NAMES = arrayOf(
        "id","city","date","player_of_match","venue","neutral_venue",
        "team1","team2","toss_winner","toss_decision",
        "winner","result","result_margin","eliminator","method","umpire1","umpire2"
```

)

> batchconfig.kt

```
package com.nilmani.dashboardipl.data

import com.nilmani.dashboardipl.entity.Match
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.builder.JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.builder.FlatFileItemReaderBuilder
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource
import javax.sql.DataSource


@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
class BatchConfig {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var jobBuilderFactory: JobBuilderFactory
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var stepBuilderFactory: StepBuilderFactory
    val FIELD_NAMES = arrayOf(
        "id","city","date","player_of_match","venue","neutral_venue",
        "team1","team2","toss_winner","toss_decision",
        "winner","result","result_margin","eliminator","method","umpire1","umpire2"
    )

    @Bean
    fun reader(): FlatFileItemReader<MatchInput> {
        return FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<MatchInput>()
            .name("MatchItemReader")
            .resource(ClassPathResource("result-match-metadata.csv"))
            .delimited()
            .names(*FIELD_NAMES)
            .fieldSetMapper(object : BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<MatchInput>() {
                init {
                    setTargetType(MatchInput::class.java)
                }
            })
            .build()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show a snippet of the CSV file?

Comment: I ALREAADY ADDED IT PLEASE CHECK ITT

Comment: Can you please show what `FIELD_NAMES` is? Additionally, have you tried with a simpler CSV file? Maybe the issue is not the code but the file.

Comment: I provide FEELD_NAMES you can check it

Comment: Looks ok. Have you tried with a simpler CSV file? Maybe the issue is not the code but the file.

Comment: you are correct it is wrong in my csv file, my batchconfig is not able to set the path of the csv file

Comment: The data is indeed wrong in the CSV file? Sorry, I didn't fully understand your comment.

Comment: FlatFileParseException Parsing  issue

Comment: Ok, I am getting even more confused. Now you are getting a `FlatFileParseException`? With the exact same file or a new one?

Comment: yes. I  already my batch config file

Comment: This seems the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69314582/flatfileparseexception-parsing-class-path-resource-error-in-spring-batch. I added an answer there. you need to skip the first line.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are missing a no-arg constructor in `MatchInput`. You are using `BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper` to map a `FieldSet` to an object. If you check the reference documentation for "setTargetType(type)", you will find the following:

> An object of this type will be created from its default constructor
> for every call to mapFieldSet(FieldSet).

Try adding a no-arg constructor to `MatchInput` as follows:

```kotlin
data class MatchInput(
    val id: String? = null,
    val city: String? = null,
    val date: String? = null,
    val player_of_match: String? = null,
    val venue: String? = null,
    val neutral_venue: String? = null,
    val team1: String? = null,
    val team2: String? = null,
    val toss_winner: String? = null,
    val toss_decision: String? = null,
    val winner: String? = null,
    val result: String? = null,
    val result_margin: String? = null,
    val eliminator: String? = null,
    val method: String? = null,
    val umpire1: String? = null,
    val umpire2: String? = null
) {
    constructor() : this(null)
}
```