# FlatFileParseException Parsing class path resource error in spring batch

Tags: kotlin, spring-batch

> I want to set classPath resource of csv file . Which is present in my
> project resource folder. When set the class Path and run the project I
> get issue in runtime issue of classpath resource
> here is the issue

```
org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException: Parsing error at line: 1 in resource=[class path resource [result-match-metadata.csv]], input=[id   city    date    player_of_match venue   neutral_venue   team1   team2   toss_winner toss_decision   winner  result  result_margin   eliminator  method  umpire1 umpire2]
```

> result-match-metadata.csv file is present inside my resource folder
> Batchconfig.kt

```
package com.nilmani.dashboardipl.data

import com.nilmani.dashboardipl.entity.Match
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.builder.JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.builder.FlatFileItemReaderBuilder
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource
import javax.sql.DataSource


@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
class BatchConfig {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var jobBuilderFactory: JobBuilderFactory
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var stepBuilderFactory: StepBuilderFactory
    val FIELD_NAMES = arrayOf(
        "id","city","date","player_of_match","venue","neutral_venue",
        "team1","team2","toss_winner","toss_decision",
        "winner","result","result_margin","eliminator","method","umpire1","umpire2"
    )

    @Bean
    fun reader(): FlatFileItemReader<MatchInput> {
        return FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<MatchInput>()
            .name("MatchItemReader")
            .resource(ClassPathResource("result-match-metadata.csv"))
            .delimited()
            .names(*FIELD_NAMES)
            .fieldSetMapper(object : BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<MatchInput>() {
                init {
                    setTargetType(MatchInput::class.java)
                }
            })
            .build()
    }
}
```

> how to set csv file path in batch config

Answer (score 1):

The resource is correctly found. The error means that the first line cannot be mapped to an instance of `MatchInput`. You just need to skip the header with `FlatFileItemReaderBuilder#linesToSkip(1)` in your item reader definition.

Comment: If I add linesToSkip(1) in FlatFileItemReaderBuilde obviously it will throw another run time error  like this "Parsing error at line: 2 in resource=[class path resource ".lineToSkip() function skip the line but not the error it take the error to the next line .which is stupid idea